# Assertions in verilog

Tags: verilog, assert, verification

I am new to verilog so please be easy.

Are assertions available in verilog ? Or are they a part of systemVerilog ?

Like most new comers, I have grabbed a book on verilog and it includes a chapter on verification ( which has assertions in it ; more than 2 dozens of them) . It also mentions OVL which I guess has some sort of header files ( or library containing these definitions) .

But google primarily displays results for assertions in systemVerilog not verilog. Add more to that, I am using Xilinx ISE 14.7 and Spartan 3A starter board as device . Xilinx Website mentions systemVerilog is supported only by Vivado design suite , but this suite does not support Spartan 3A board (I dont know systemVerilog either) .

So given all this, I am a little confused. How do I learn assert based verification in verilog . Is such thing even there in verilog ( I assume it's there in verilog because it's a verilog book )? . Is there some way I can do this is xilinx ise 14.7 ? I also have access to modelsim student edition for simulation, if that can help.

Comment: google produced a link to the Xilinx forums with a similar question: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/System-Verilog-assertions-in-Verilog-code/td-p/326471.

Comment: @wilcroft . The link assumes knowledge and access to systemVerilog tools. I guess there is no way to use assertions with verilog. But the book I am using uses verilog 2001 and assertions from OVL library in alongwith verilog modules. How is that so ?

Answer (score 2):

`Assert`ion constructs were added to the SystemVerilog Language, not Verilog. However, an *assertion* is just statement of truth, and any self-checking testbench could be called a collection of assertions.

Assertion constructs in SystemVerilog provide a formalized standard for writing temporal expressions for testing their validity, plus a standardized metric for coverage reporting - i.e. not only tells if the assertion passed or failed, but how far it was exercised or not.

The OVL library is library of assertion expressions written in a variety of languages including Verilog and SystemVerilog. The SystemVerilog flavor is naturally more efficient, plus it gives you the additional coverage metrics.

Comment: Dave. You mentioned OVL library is available for verilog as well . Then how do I use it ? ( Remember I only know basic - intermediate level verilog and have only used it for synthesis until now , with simple testbenches . I dont know verification much )

Comment: http://www.eda.org/ovl/ and https://verificationacademy.com/sessions/introduction-open-verification-library